# Can I say 'he works away and away'?

Tags: grammar, expressions, idiomatic-language

> Can I say 'he works away and away'?

work away means work hard and I wonder if I can use the 'away' once again with and together.

Comment: You are consciously using the word _away_ in two different senses. This might be an example of [zeugma](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/zeugma), but I'm not sure it's successful, because we usually say that someone is working away _at_ something.

Comment: No, you can't. You can say *He was **up and away*** (he got up and left), or *He works **on and on*** (ceaselessly). As @KateBunting says, you can't idiomatically repeat ***away*** with the ***same*** sense to optionally convey emphasis (as with ***on***), nor can you "naturally" use the word twice with ***different*** meanings (he works ***diligently*** AND where he works is ***somewhere other than*** his normal location).

Comment: You could conceivably say "He works away at [his job], away in [town]", but it sounds awfully clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

"work away" meaning "work hard" is a bit of a simplification of the actual meaning. Usually when people say somebody is "working away", it means that they have been working hard for a very long time without stopping. However, saying "works away and away" usually means that they are working so hard for so long that it is becoming all they do in life.

Comment: Thx. You think 'study away' could mean study without stopping?

Comment: Yes (this is just extra text to reach the minimum character limit)

Comment: Note that ***away*** in such contexts can often imply "without hindrance" rather than "without stopping". This is particularly noticeable if we compare an "assertion" context like *I've been **working away** all afternoon, so I could use a break.* with an "imperative" utterance like *There's plenty of food, so **eat away**, guys!*

Comment: Thx. Fumble. 'sing far away' could mean 'sing without any hindrance'—added 'far' to emphasize.